# Derivative of sup(max) functions in distributionally robust optimization

Tags: stochastic-programming, robust-optimization

In the distributionally robust optimization problem
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x\in X}\sup_{P\in\mathfrak{P}}\mathbb{E}_P[f(x,\xi)],
\end{aligned}
where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $P$ is a distribution function over the measurable set $\mathfrak{P}$, and $\mathbb{E}_P$ denotes the expected value with respect to the distribution $P$.

For a differentiable function $f$, if we define $g(x):=\sup_{P\in\mathfrak{P}} \mathbb{E}_P[f(x,\xi)]$, is the function $g$ differentiable for the variable $x$ like $\nabla g(x)=\sup_{P\in\mathfrak{P}}\mathbb{E}_P[\nabla_x f(x,\xi)]$?

In general, I guess it is not true because the interchangeability of the differentiation and expectation operators cannot hold.
But I am curious what is the condition that the following equation holds?
\begin{aligned}
\nabla g(x)=\sup_{P\in\mathfrak{P}}\mathbb{E}_P[\nabla_x f(x,\xi)].
\end{aligned}

Comment: did you try the definition of expectation

Comment: While I am not attempting to answer your question in this comment, you may be interested to know that even sup and $\nabla$ cannot be interchanged. So the problem may be beyond just the issue of interchangeability between differentiation ($\nabla$) and expectation.

Comment: I would answer this question by myself.

If the following conditions hold, the equality $\nabla g(x)=\sup_{P\in\mathfrak{P}} \mathbb{E}_P[\nabla_{x} f(x,\xi)]$ holds:

1. the set $\mathfrak{P}$ is weakly compact;
 
2. the optimal element $P\in\mathfrak{P}$ is uniquely determined;

3. the function $f$ is regular.

The condition might be stricter than I expected, though.